# UI problem after dismissing UIActionSheet within UIPopoverController

Tags: ipad, toolbar, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

I'm having a problem with a specific use of a UIActionSheet within a UIPopoverController.  It seems to be an Apple bug, but I wanted to check here first to make sure I'm not missing something.  The conditions to reproduce the problem are quite specific, so I've created a small app that reproduces the problem.  You can [download that here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4361885/UIActionSheetProblem/iPadSplitBug.zip).

The problem happens under the following conditions:

- A UIPopoverController contains a UINavigationController.
- The `setToolbarHidden:` method has been called on the UINavigationController to show the toolbar, but the toolbar is in a hidden state when displaying the UIActionSheet.

Once the UIActionSheet is displayed and dismissed, the navigation controller gets resized as if a toolbar should be displayed below it (or perhaps it is the toolbar?).  Calling `setToolbarHidden:YES` in `-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` doesn't help.

You can reproduce the problem by downloading the project above, running it in the iPad simulator (iOS4.2) in portrait orientation, and tapping "Tap Me" in the UIPopoverController.  Once the UIAlertView is dismissed you'll see the problem.  Below is a screenshot.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

[image]